# Linux take screenshot when menu is open

Tags: screenshot

I have a GTK application in C++ running, and one of the widgets is a dropdown menu. I want to take a screenshot when this menu is open, but nothing happens when I press Print Screen (it works when the menu is closed). I don't think this is a GTK thing: how can I take a screenshot when the menu is open?

Comment: Use `gnome-screenshot --interactive` in terminal and set a delay, then go back to your app and open that menu and wait...

Comment: @don_crissti please don't answer questions in the comments.

Comment: @don_crissti that'll do, cheers.